# Conditioned based Running total

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am rewriting this Post!

This is my Query

```
SELECT ITEMNUM,
  STORELOC,
  TRANSDATE,
  ACTUALDATE,
  CONDITIONCODE,
  ISSUETYPE,
  QUANTITY,
  CURBAL,
  '' AS Balnce_In_Condition_02,
  ENTERBY,
  MEMO,
  DOCNUM
FROM MATUSETRANS
WHERE ITEMNUM = 'Z95-04-BHH811550'
AND STORELOC  ='04'
AND TRANSDATE >'01-JAN-19'
ORDER BY TRANSDATE DESC;
```

and it is my result

[image]

I need running Balance_In_Condition_02 which I write separately in image. Basically my need is to create a Inventory report of Items which is issue from CONDITIONCODE 01 while the same item was present in CONDITIONCODE 02. Items are frequently ISSUE and RETURN. Hope you can understand my question

Comment: Hi @user2807258, do not know for others but for me your description is very very hard to understand. Please try harder to explain what you need and then when you are done read it yourself and try to see if you will understand it without any effort - that is how you will know it will be ok for us...

Comment: Hope now question is understandable.

Comment: `Since there is 2 item return at 3rd level record` what do you want to say here ? And what do you want to say with CONDITION  02 and CONDITION  01 ?

Comment: When ever any Item return on Condition 02 then sum of total quantity of Condition 02 will be shown at BALANCEINCON2 column. Since in my record there is 0 item on condition 02 at that time then 0+2=2 at condition 02. But if any item present at condition 02 the sum will be sown at BALANCEINCON2 column. I need sum of condition 02 items in BALANCEINCON2 based on TRANSDATE.

Comment: I am sorry but this does not help to me. Maybe to someone else it will. I do not see any column here called Condition 02 or Condition 01 and if you are refering to first and second condition in your where clause then this explanation is not clear to me at all... Best of luck!

Comment: Condition code  id shown in CONDITIONCODE column

Answer (score 0):

At first sum quantity conditionally, only for rows with `conditioncode = '02'`, like in my inner query. Then use analytic `lead()` to fill values for the rest of rows.

```
select itemnum, storeloc, transdate, quantity, conditioncode,
       nvl(bal02, lead(bal02) ignore nulls 
         over (partition by itemnum order by transdate desc)) balance02
  from (
    select itemnum, storeloc, transdate, quantity, conditioncode,
           case conditioncode when '02' then sum(quantity) 
             over (partition by itemnum order by transdate desc) end bal02
      from matusetrans mtu
      where itemnum = 'Z95-04-B806073A' and storeloc = '04')
  order by transdate desc;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e421cf88994fd93a4b13b087a8f33a4)</sup>**

I am not sure if you are summing all quantities or only `02` rows, because in your example these sums are equal. In this second case instead of `sum(quantity)` use:

```
sum(case conditioncode when '02' then quantity end) over (...
```